# Is it possible to use PHP glob() in another domain?

Tags: php, file, filesystems, glob

If I use blob with a relative path I would use something like this:

```
$files = glob("../uploads/*");
```

If I want to check if another website (but in the same hosting account) has the files, can I use this?:

```
$files = glob("http://myothersite.com/uploads/*");
```

I also want to know if it is possible to delete files in another domain, like the example above but using:

```
unlink("http://myotherwebsite.com/uploads/file.jpg");
```

EDIT:

Thinking about it, if I want to delete files in another domain, I would have to create a webservice or something with the proper validation so it knows the deletion is being requested by a safe source.

For example a php file that receives GET or POST parameters to know what file will be removed, then do the unlink() process. But that function, for obvious reasons, does not work from foreign apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing. I assume you talk about `glob()` function and not `blob()`. If so please correct your question.

If website is at the same hosting account, you probably may navigate to other paths in your account.

Let's assume you have files inside:

```
/home/yourname/site1
/home/yourname/site2
/home/yourname/site3
```

Then you can simple use `glob('/home/yourname/site3');` when you run it at your site1 url. You simple don't need to use urls firm `glob()` and in fact you can't:

> ```
> Note: This function will not work on remote files as the file to be examined must be accessible via the server's filesystem.
> ```

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand why I had in my mind "blob" after using it hundred of times. Thanks for the reply!